# Is it possible to export class from one module to another module in Angular 2?

Tags: class, angular

I would like to know, exporting **class** from one (custom) **module** to another **module** (Main app module), is it possible and is it right approach ?

As per my knowledge we can export component, directive and pipes.

Because when I try to use particular class from other module  folder, it directly refers it, like *'../pathToClass/abc.class.ts'*. Which I don't think proper separation .

I am using class as **POJO (TypeScript: Interface)** to input for my custom component.

Let me know, if need more details or If question is not clear.

Comment: What is a POJO in this context? That's a Java term.

Comment: he meant to say that he is using an interface to bind the data in angular 2..as i understand

Comment: @Jonrsharpe, Vikeam Pawar is right, Here POJO means Type Script interface, which is bridge here for my custom component and outside modules.